# Merge files in Unix per lines

Tags: unix, merge, ascii, text-files, concatenation

I have two txt files, first one contains:

```
    000
    111
    222
    333
    444
```

and the second one contains:

```
    .
```

How can I merge this two text files in the unix terminal, so I can get another file that contains:

```
    .000
    .111
    .222
    .333
    .444
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

The `paste` command is generally what you're looking for, but it expects both files to have the same number of lines.    You can create a file with the same number of lines repeated with something like  `yes $(cat file2) | head -$(wc -l < file1)`

So the whole thing, using bash file substitution:

```
 paste -d "" <(yes $(cat file2) | head -$(wc -l <file1)) file1
```